# Using Typedef to store elements in a 2D Array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

I'm changing a program I've already completed (that uses 4 arrays) into a new program that uses typedef to create a structure that holds those arrays, so I'm only using one instead.

To do this, I used this code:

```
typedef struct structure
{
char names[13][9];
int scores[13][4];
float average[13];   
char letter[13];
} stuff;
```

The one array that now contains all of these is:

```
stuff everything[13];
```

However I'm running into a few complications since 'names' 'scores' 'average' and 'letter' no longer exist, I have to change it to go through the typedef instead. So, as an example, I have this code:

```
for(i=0; i<13; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
    fscanf(score, "%d", &scores[i][j]);
    }
}   
fclose(score);
```

How would I get it to store the information in the 'scores' array still?

Also how would I later call the information out of that array?

Comment: So as you have it declared `everything` is an array of `13 stuff` but the loop does not look like you intended that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have `scores`, it's just inside the structure. You can access it using normal array and structure access operators:

```
everything[x].scores[i][j] = 6;
```

`x` has to be between `0` and `12` (inclusive) as you declared `everything` to be `13` of `stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 stuff everything[13];
```

declares an array of 13 structs with type `stuff`. It is equivalent to

```
 struct structure everything[13];
```

with `typedef`, you don't need to write `struct structure` again.

In order to access information from the above array of structs, you may do something like the following for `scores` (similar reasoning apply to other fields:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i )
 {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 13; ++j)
    {
       for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
       {
           printf("%d ", everything[i].scores[j][k]);
       }
   }
 }
```

When you want to put stuff into this array of structs, you should follow the same logic as above.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what you want is something like this:

```
#define NUM_TEAMS 13
typedef struct 
{
    char names[9];
    int scores[4];
    float average;   
    char letter;
} team; 

team everything[NUM_TEAMS];

int readInScores(team* allTeams)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j= 0;
    FILE* score = fopen("whatever", "r");
    if (score == 0)
        return 0;
    for(i=0; i<NUM_TEAMS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            fscanf(score, "%d",&allTeams[i].scores[j]);
        }
    }   
    fclose(score);
    return 1;
}
```